# How to solve "org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity [Table Name]"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, intellij-idea

The below block of code is not working:

```
private boolean checkLaptopDuplicates(String data1) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    String stmt = "from laptop where image_url = '" + data1 + "'";
    List<Laptop> laptopList = session.createQuery(stmt).getResultList();
    return laptopList.size() > 0;

}
```

I got the following error with the above block of code:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'Laptop'
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:761)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:127)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy47.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at web_scraping_codes.scraping_codes.LaptopDataAccessObject.checkLaptopDuplicates(LaptopDataAccessObject.java:90)
    at web_scraping_codes.scraping_codes.LaptopDataAccessObject.addLaptop(LaptopDataAccessObject.java:42)
    at web_scraping_codes.scraping_codes.ValueComputersScraper.run(ValueComputersScraper.java:153)
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'Laptop'
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1628)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$RootEntityContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1873)
```

How this issue should be tackled?

Comment: You need to add more details (entity class and persistence.xml or other file you use for configuration). Probably, you haven't annotated the class `Laptop` with `@Entity`, or you haven't added it in the configuration file.